# Scale effect in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create the following CSS effect:

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
transform: scale(0.92);
```

using Jquery. It is a button click effect where it bounces in and out on hover/ click. However, the following scale effect doesn't provide the necessary effect for me. Any help would be great!

```
$(".ico-btttn").show( "scale", {percent: 0.92, direction: 'vertical' }
```

```css
.ico-btttn {
    margin-right: 0px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .07s ease-out; 
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform .07s ease-out; 
   -o-transition: -o-transform .07s ease-out; 
    transition: transform .07s ease-out; 
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:pink;
}

.ico-btttn:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.92);
    transform: scale(0.92);
    opacity: 0.80;
    color:#89df88;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

```html
<div role="button" class="ico-btttn">HELP</div>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what "the necessary effect" is?

Comment: Hi @KoshVery, thanks for your response. The effect can be seen in the attached code snippet (Run code snippet). It is done with CSS, but I'd like to substitute that effect with the JQuery one.

Comment: Why do you need to use jQuery?

Comment: Because the div has two animation properties on it. And since some Android devices only support one animation property, I am hoping for a JS fallback.

Comment: Which "animation properties" are you talking about? Please be clear.

Comment: Using jQuery nowadays for animation purposes is discouraged in favor of CSS3 transition and animation. Use JS to handle events and eventually assign/toggle classes - that trigger such a CSS effect.